# Drawing shapes without visual studio designer. Shapes not showing and events not firing

Tags: c#

I am simply trying to draw some shapes without the use of visual studio functionality, most tutorials use that, and I am reasonbly sure that the coding is different because of that, so last resort was to ask here.

Following some guides on forms, that didn't use any visual studio (and yeah, I know that it is much easier with it, but using such things has screwed me in the past, so wanna learn without) I got the form made and such, but when it came to actually drawing shapes, I hit a wall.

I did a bit of debugging, from what I have been able to determine, the event does not fire at all. And the graphics code in the main function does nothing, just a blank form shows up. 
I tried a couple of variations on both the in-main code, and the event code, which is visible in the code, I also tried using a variant of the event that used a "sender" argument, no idea if changing that made any difference, none of them fired anyways.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Workflow.ComponentModel;

class Genetics : Form
{

    public static Form form1;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        form1 = new Form();
        form1.Size = new Size(800, 800);

        Pen blackpen = new Pen(Color.Black, 10);
        Graphics G = form1.CreateGraphics();

        G.DrawRectangle(blackpen, form1.Width - form1.Width / 2, form1.Width - form1.Width / 2, 300, 300);

      form1.CreateGraphics().DrawRectangle(blackpen, form1.Width -    form1.Width / 2, form1.Width - form1.Width / 2, 300, 300);

        Application.Run(form1);


    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {        
        Graphics graphics;
        graphics = form1.CreateGraphics();

        Pen mypen = new Pen(Color.Black, 5);

        graphics.DrawLine(mypen, 20, 20, 200, 210);

        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(mypen, 20, 20, 200, 210);

    }


}
```

I don't get any errors or anything, it just... Doesn't do anything, other than shows the form, but that is a bit of a bare minimum.

I know this is probarbly easy to fix, but again, all tutorials used visual studio forms, and unsure if the code was different. Since I have tried straight up copying that code and it gave me errors, I assume I am correct, but not 100% sure. 
And I am reasonbly experienced, I am just used to writing in unity, the process of going from there to pure code has been difficult for me though.

Comment: Don't create a new `Graphics` object, use the one given to you in your `PaintEventArgs` (`e.Graphics`).  If for some reason you ever do create a new `Graphics` (which you don't need to do here - just repeating), make sure you `Dispose` it (typically with a `using` statement).  Graphics objects wrap Win32 _Device Contexts_, and they need to be aggressively released.

Comment: You have got to get a book or follow a tutorial, WinForm graphics are too complicated to guess your way.

Comment: Yeah, listen to @DourHighArch.  I just looked at your `Main` func (originally, I only looked at your `OnPaint`).  Creating a `Graphics` there is useless, as is trying to draw onto your form (although the `Form` object is created, until you call `Application.Run` on it (and a whole lot of behind-the-scenes code runs), you don't have a window, so there's nothing to draw on.  In Windows Forms, you should do all your drawing in `OnPaint` using the `e.Graphics`.  You control when `OnPaint` runs by carefully invalidating parts of your window. All this dates back to Win32 (which WinForms wraps)

Comment: @Flydog57 Hmm, I do generally want to find tutorials, the problem was just that I saw a difference between using the built in visual studio functionalities, and just pure coding it. How big is the difference there? And is there a difference at all? Just asking tp know if the tutorials using the visual studio functionalities when it comes to forms, is actually useable.

Comment: _difference between using the built in visual studio functionalities, and just pure coding_ I have __no idea__ what you might mean by that. What 'visual studio functionalities' do you have in mind??? - `graphics = form1.CreateGraphics();` should be `Graphics graphics = e.Graphics;` for starters.

Comment: @TaW 
Well, what I am talking about is the designer that visual studio offers. Seems to appear when using the "Windows form app" template. From what I have been able to see, it seems like there are some things that are unique to it, like events that seem to assume that the code is "placed" on a form Fx ones that are formatted like this [name of form]_[event form, fx MouseDown] (PaintEventArgs). 
I might just genuinly be an idiot right now, but that designer has a bunch of functionalities, so linking files more easily would make sense, in my mind at least.

Comment: So you mean the forms designer? (Not some old paint tool, which at some point used to be included in some VS versions??). Yes the forms designer is meant to compose forms and user controls by adding controls and styling them along with docking and anchoring behaviour. Pretty much no graphics there beyond setting backcolors. Absolutely everything you do in the designer is reflected in the xxDesigner.cs files meaning that it is all in code as well!

Comment: @TaW Edited my previous comment to explain better, just woke up so acidentally pressed enter without holding shift...
But yes, the forms designer, everyone seems to use it, and from what I have searched for here, everyone recommends it, but again, I am not a fan of using such built in functions, since I have had enough hardships with going from Unity's simplified Libraries to console coding.
And yeah, from what I have seen there aren't any graphics there, but it seems to make the process of connecting the form to the code easier and more standardized, if that makes sense?

Comment: It certainly help to use a wysiwyg editor to compose the surface and its potentially very many parts (Controls).. All the real work will still happen in the editor and that will include all graphics coding.

Comment: @TaW Hey, just wanted to thank you, finding out that the code for the designer existed (although a tad hidden) in a .cs file helped a ton, and I got my script to work. So thanks :)

Comment: Glad to hear that. Do note the other comments though, as the basics of winforms graphics are essential to get the desired results and not all examples, esp. on MSDN get it quite right..

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone other than me was looking for this, the problem was two main things:
1, the events weren't connected to anything, so I needed to add a line like this:

```
[Form variable].[form event] += new PaintEventHandler([Class].[Method with an object sender and an event argument]
//Example of that
form1.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(Genetics.Paint);
```

Without this, nothing will happen since the methods and events aren't connected.

2, mostly a repeat of the comments, I needed to have all the draw functions in events, since they won't have anything to draw to, before the application is actually run. Then it's just a matter of invalidating the code inside those events, to force the form to be redrawn.